# Separating objects in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, counting, image-segmentation, object-detection

I'm trying to count objects in an image and the MATLAB script I wrote works well but some objects are touching (in other image they are even overlapping) and it counts only one object instead of two. I am trying to use the `bwdist` function associated to the watershed function to separate these objects but it doesn't work well.  It cuts my objects at many parts where it shouldn't and the counting is much worse.

If somebody could explain me how to proceed in other to separate the good particles (the 2 touching at the right of my image) I would be grateful.

Here is the image:

[image]

---

Here is my code (if you run it a lot of figures will appear):

Sorry for writing the comments in french =P

```
clear all;

k=1; % indice pour la numérotation des images
I=imread('Images particules/DSC_0037.jpg');
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I);

I_hsv=rgb2hsv(I);
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I_hsv);

I_h=I_hsv(:,:,1);
I_s=I_hsv(:,:,2);
I_v=I_hsv(:,:,3);

figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I_h)
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I_s)
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I_v)

%% Hue

[Gx, Gy] = imgradientxy(I_h);
[Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
% figure(k);
% k=k+1;
% imshowpair(Gmag, Gdir, 'montage');

I_bw1=Gmag>mean(quantile(Gmag,0.99));
figure(k);
k=k+1;
imshowpair(Gmag,I_bw1,'montage');

%% Saturation

[Gx, Gy] = imgradientxy(I_s);
[Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
% figure(k);
% k=k+1;
% imshowpair(Gmag, Gdir, 'montage');

I_bw2=Gmag>mean(quantile(Gmag,0.99));
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshowpair(Gmag,I_bw2,'montage');


%% Variance

[Gx, Gy] = imgradientxy(I_v);
[Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
% figure(k);
% k=k+1;
% imshowpair(Gmag, Gdir, 'montage');

I_bw3=Gmag>mean(quantile(Gmag,0.99)); % choisir le bon quantile
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshowpair(Gmag,I_bw3,'montage');

%% Addition images du gradient

I_recomp=I_bw1+I_bw2+I_bw3;

figure(k);
k=k+1;
imshow(I_recomp);

%% Dilatation - fill - erosion

% Element structurant diamond
% Dilatation
SE=strel('octagon',3); % doit être un multiple de 3 !
I_dil=imdilate(I_recomp,SE);
% figure(k)
% k=k+1;
% imshow(I_dil);

% Fill
I_fill=imfill(I_dil,'holes');

% Erosion
I_er=imerode(I_fill,SE);
% figure(k)
% k=k+1;
% imshow(I_er);

%% Elimination du bruit en appliquant un imerode <taille minimale des plastiques en pixels
% Erosion - dilatation

SE=strel('octagon',6); % mesurer la taille maximale d'un plastic en pixel avec imdistline !
I_bruit=imdilate(imerode(I_er,SE),SE);
figure(k)
k=k+1;
imshow(I_bruit);

%% Séparation des particules avec watershed

I_bwdist=-bwdist(~I_bruit);
figure(k);
k=k+1;
imshow(I_bwdist,[]);

I_water=watershed(I_bwdist);
I_bruit(I_water==0)=0;
figure(k);
k=k+1;
imshow(I_bruit);

%% Comptage des particules

cc=bwconncomp(I_bruit);
cc.NumObjects
L=labelmatrix(cc);
RGB_label=label2rgb(L);
figure(k);
k=k+1;
imshow(RGB_label);
```

Comment: 1.) I cannot access the image you link to. 2.) By what metric do you want to distinguish between overlapping objects? 3.) Why doesn't a cut work? I imagine two overlapping circles - but I can only see the top one. Hence I have no idea what the shape below actually looks like. Please clarify this.

Comment: 1) I can't understand why you cannot read my image ? For me it works well by clicking on the link and downloading. 2) what is a metric ? By visual inspection it is obvious that the 2 particles are different objects. 3) What do you mean by cut ? You have to imagine 2 random size particles (it can be circles, lines, squares and so on but never perfect geometric objects...)
Plz tell me if you still can't open my image. If not I will try to post it on an other server.

Comment: @Zoran - I have downloaded your image and placed it in your post.  I also think you're on the right track.  You can definitely use the Hue here to help you.  The objects have very distinct colours.  Perhaps detect what the hue is of the background, then do some sort of Boolean expressions to remove the background

Answer (score 3):

This is a not trivial problem and there are many possible solutions.
Note: I haven't used `imgradientxy` and `imgradient` as in your code because my matlab version is too old (R2011b).

In my opinion, there are at least two necessary things to do:

- separation of background from other objects. In this case I use this implementation of Otsu thresholding (executed on the image converted in HSV channels with a four class level threshold):

  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26532-image-segmentation-using-otsu-thresholding

  It could be helpful a different color background.
- analyze every object alone to avoid interferences.
  It's possible to perform different type of analysis:

  - math morphological operations: `imerode`/`imdilate`
  - texture segmentation (gabor filter, entropy, homogeneity or intensity level). Here some examples:

    http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-1.html

    Also check the guide to segmentation with gabor filter and the pages with examples and concepts.

Personally I first execute a phase of `imerode`/`imdilate` operations to slice the initial objects.

I think it's better to erase sub-objects too small:

- with an additional erosion passage, using a small struct-element
- `bwareaopen` with a small percentage of the total area of the initial object.

If any sub-objects still exists, should be possible to better separate the sub-objects with one of the technique listed above.
I use math morphology (erosion is a little slow), Otsu segmentation again, image difference and eventually `bwselect` to control the result.

Here my code and output.

```matlab
clear all;
close all;
clc;

n_level = 4;
channel_n = 2;
R1_perc = 1 / 8;
R2_perc = 5 / 100;
area2_perc = 2 / 100;
R3_small = 1;
I = imread('~/Downloads/25443957.jpg');
I_hsv = rgb2hsv(I);

% % indentify image background as the object with greatest area
% original Otsu implementation
Ihsv_otsu = otsu(I_hsv, n_level);

areas_extension = zeros(1, n_level);
for x = 1:n_level
    img_area_object = Ihsv_otsu == x; % img_zona = (Ihsv_otsu_bwl==n);
    areas_extension(1, x) = bwarea(img_area_object);
end
[background_val, background_idx] = max(areas_extension);
Ihsv_otsu_filled = imfill(Ihsv_otsu ~= background_idx, 'holes');

% % divide et impera
% analyze the objects one by one
Ihsv_otsu_bwl = bwlabel(Ihsv_otsu_filled);
img_morph = zeros(size(Ihsv_otsu_bwl));
img_eroded = zeros(size(Ihsv_otsu_bwl));

SE1px1 = strel('disk', 1);
SE3small = strel('disk', R3_small);

fprintf('start loop MORPH, Operations:: erosion & dilate...\n')

for n = 1:max(unique(Ihsv_otsu_bwl))
    fprintf('morph loop... iter:%d\n', n)
    img_zona = Ihsv_otsu_bwl == n;
 
    temp = regionprops(img_zona, 'MinorAxisLength');
    minoraxis = temp.MinorAxisLength;
 
    img_zona_out = img_zona;
    R = ceil(minoraxis * R1_perc); % use 'ceil', not 'round', to avoid R<1 processing small regions
    SE2R1 = strel('disk', R);
 
    CC = bwconncomp(img_zona_out, 8);
    k = 0;
    while CC.NumObjects == 1
        img_zona_out = imerode(img_zona_out, SE2R1);
        CC = bwconncomp(img_zona_out, 8);
        k = k + 1;
     
        % %% it is possible to erode with size~1-pixel object or not
        %         if CC.NumObjects>1
        %             fprintf('FOUND! iter:%d, c_EROSION:%d, n_Obj:%d\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
        %         elseif CC.NumObjects==0
        %             fprintf('BREAK! iter:%d, c_EROSION:%d, n_Obj:%d\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
        %             break
        %         %elseif CC.NumObjects==1
        %         %    fprintf('keep carry on... iter:%d, c_EROSION:%d, n_Obj:%d\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
        %         end
        if CC.NumObjects > 1
            img_zona_out = imerode(img_zona_out, SE3small);
            CC = bwconncomp(img_zona_out, 8);
            if CC.NumObjects > 1
                 fprintf('FOUND! iter:%d, c_EROSION:%d, n_Obj:%d\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
            elseif CC.NumObjects == 0
                % fprintf('BREAK! iter:%d, c_EROSION:%d, n_Obj:%d\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
                break
            end
        end
    end
 
    % %% post-erosion:
    % if the object number is 0, drop the eroded image and mantain the pre-eroded image
    if CC.NumObjects == 0
        img_morph = imadd(img_morph > 0, img_zona);
        img_eroded = imadd(img_eroded > 0, img_zona);
        continue
        % if the object number is greater than 1,  dilate the objects until
        % they touch, when the CC.NumObjects is 1
    elseif CC.NumObjects > 1
     
        k = 0;
        img_zona_dilate = img_zona_out;
        while CC.NumObjects > 1
            k = k + 1;
            img_zona_old = img_zona_dilate;
            % a small radius is better for a uniform expansion
            img_zona_dilate = imdilate(img_zona_dilate, SE3small);
            CC = bwconncomp(img_zona_dilate > 0, 8);
            if CC.NumObjects == 1
                % %% results the last objects immediatly before they touch
                img_eroded = imadd(img_eroded > 0, img_zona_old);
                fprintf('UNITED! iter:%d, c_DILATE:%d, n_n_Obj:%d\n\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
            end
        end
     
        % modified Otsu function (otsuSeparation.m)
        img_splitted = otsuSeparation(I_hsv, img_zona, channel_n, R2_perc, area2_perc);
        img_morph = imadd(img_morph > 0, img_splitted > 0);
    elseif CC.NumObjects == 1
        fprintf('# only one object... strange at this point.\n#')
        fprintf('# iter:%d, c_DILATE:%d, CC.NumObjects:%g\n', n, k, CC.NumObjects)
    end
end

% %
fprintf('start loop BWSELECT:: img_morph & img_eroded...\n')

img_eroded_bwl = bwlabel(img_eroded);

img_result = zeros(size(img_eroded_bwl));

for X = 1:max(unique(img_eroded_bwl))
    fprintf('# BWSELECT, iter:%d\n', X)
    obj2select = img_eroded_bwl == X;
    centr = regionprops(obj2select, 'centroid');
    xc = round(centr.Centroid(1));
    yc = round(centr.Centroid(2));
 
    temp = bwselect(img_morph, xc, yc);
    img_result = imadd(img_result > 0, temp);
end

img_result = img_result > 0;

%%
close all

figure('Name', 'morph', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'docked');
imagesc(img_morph)

figure('Name', 'erodeed', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'docked');
imagesc(img_eroded)

figure('Name', 'hsv', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'docked');
imagesc(I_hsv)

figure('Name', 'image', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'docked');
imagesc(I)

figure('Name', 'result', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'docked');
imagesc(img_result)
```

---

Here my modification of the Otsu function, `OtsuSeparation.m`.

```matlab
function [img_splitted] = otsuSeparation(I, bw, channel_n, R2_perc, area2_perc)
    img_splitted = zeros(size(bw));
 
    SE1px1 = strel('disk', 1);
    % fprintf('start loop: Otsu segmentation...\n')
 
    % for Y=1:max(unique(img_bwl))     %for Y=41:41
    % fprintf('# OtsuSep: iter:%d\n', Y)
    % bw = img_bwl==Y;
    img_channel = I(:, :, channel_n);
    img_channel(bw == 0) = 0;
    % image segmentation by intensity
    img_channel_otsu = otsu(img_channel);
 
    % processing "BW" to avoid multiple objects and use only one valor for MinorAxisLength
    temp2 = regionprops(bw, 'MinorAxisLength', 'Area');
    R2 = ceil(temp2.MinorAxisLength * R2_perc);
    area2 = ceil(temp2.Area * area2_perc);
    SE3R2 = strel('disk', R2);
 
    % %% PART1: cleaning principal object selected by Otsu segmentation
    % removing small objects external to main selection with bwareaopen to
    % avoid modification at object contours
    img_part1 = bwareaopen(img_channel_otsu > 1, area2, 8);
    img_part1 = imfill(img_part1, 'holes');
    % execting imdilate to avoid intersection between PART1 and PART2 complements
    img_part1 = imdilate(img_part1, SE3R2);
    img_complement1 = imcomplement(img_part1);
 
    % %% PART2: cleaning external area around PART1 object
    % execting imerode to avoid intersection between PART1 and PART2 complements
    img_bw_eroded = imerode(bw, SE3R2);
    img_complement2 = imcomplement(img_bw_eroded);
    img_part2 = img_complement1 - img_complement2;
 
    img_part2 = bwareaopen(img_part2 > 0, area2, 8);
    % dilate (after erosion) to restore original object size and morphology
    img_part2 = imdilate(img_part2, SE3R2);
 
    % securing a well-done separation between objects
    img_intersez = imadd(img_part1, img_part2) > 1;
    img_intersez = imdilate(img_intersez, SE1px1);
    % use manual substraction here instead of imabsdiff for a good separation
    img_part1 = (img_part1 - img_intersez) > 0;
    img_part2 = (img_part2 - img_intersez) > 0;
 
    img_splitted = imadd(img_splitted, imadd(img_part1, img_part2));
```

Of course it's possible perform different choices.
To improve the accuracy, it could be necessary try the algorithm with few more sample image and test it with a control group of different images.

Here my output.

Grayscale bwlabel (color version):

[image: color version]

Grayscale bwlabel (matlab raw image):

[image: bwlabel, matlab raw image]

---

**UPDATE**:
My code needs an improvement. During the "imdilate after imerode" phase, I assume that the binary object should be divided into two parts. To emprove the algorithm, It's possible to use also edge detection:

[http://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sastry/ee20/index.html](http://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esastry/ee20/index.html)

http://it.mathworks.com/help/coder/examples/edge-detection-on-images.html

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45459-canny-edge-detection-in-2-d-and-3-d

Other generic resources about image segmentation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition

http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/object-analysis.html

http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-analysis-1.html

http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-1.html

---

As alternative, you could use this approach (example in python) using connected components with stats:

[Alternative segmentation techniques other than watershed for soil particles in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345906/alternative-segmentation-techniques-other-than-watershed-for-soil-particles-in-i/60346480)

---

UPDATE2: You could also change approach using deep learning, like in these examples:

- https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-detectron2/
- https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/
- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation

---

UPDATE3: I think that [segment-anything](https://segment-anything.com/) deserves a special mention because of its effectiveness. Here my result with the question image: note that segment-anything separates correctly the two overlapping stones on the right but doesn't find some small other ones

[image: segmented-image-by-segment-anything]

Comment: Here the results (bwlabeled, color version):
https://goo.gl/photos/7BGdmiMCowvcLb4q8

Comment: Here the results (bwlabeled, matlab raw image):
https://goo.gl/photos/AWz1h9fXCBar9dn59

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation is always a difficult problem. It's quite hard to answer in general what is the best way of solving your problem, I'd imagine that in each image the overlapping particles would look different. You could use shape, color, texture, prior knowledge (training), etc. You data will probably dictate what will work best

I will just describe here a simple method for separating touching particles rely on shape of particles and is known as [watershed separation](http://fiji.sc/Nuclei_Watershed_Separation). 
The process starts with a binary image (which you already obtained by thresholding). Then you would compute the distance map ([bwdist](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html)). Then one option is to progressively [dilate](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) the [ultimately eroded points](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwulterode.html) until they meet a black pixel which would use to form your separation segment.